# Multiply time with a decimal value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to multiply a time with decimal value but not to get it right. That is, when I multiply with any decimal value, it is rounding that value to nearest integer and then doing the multiplication.

For Example: All the below operations are resulting the same value

```
1. '00:04:18' * 1.7 = '00:08:36'
2. '00:04:18' * 1.8 = '00:08:36'
3. '00:04:18' * 1.9 = '00:08:36'
4. '00:04:18' * 2 = '00:08:36'
```

Please let me know what change I have to do to get the accurate value without rounding.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SEC_TO_TIME( TIME_TO_SEC( '00:04:18' ) * 1.7 ) = '00:07:18.6'
SEC_TO_TIME( TIME_TO_SEC( '00:04:18' ) * 1.7 ) = '00:07:44.4'

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using

Comment: I use stored proc where I have two variables like "DECLARE _median_time TIME;" and "DECLARE _percentage_change INT;"  and the return value is "RETURN SEC_TO_TIME( TIME_TO_SEC(_median_time) * _percentage_change);" which is not working

Comment: select SEC_TO_TIME( TIME_TO_SEC( '00:04:18' ) * 1.9) ; works but not in stored proc.

Comment: Got it. I had to change the datatype of _percentage_change  to Decimal(3, 2) from INT. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I hadn't read your reply properly & used FLOAT & was wondering why it still worked